# Intent de AsyncTask a navigationActivity

Tags: android-studio

Intento enviar datos a otra activity desde el onPostExecute de mi asyncTask, el problemas es que no hace nada. en LOGCAT me lanza el error:

> W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.filmotek.MainActivity$LoginTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:66)

Linea 66 es la de

```
b.putString("name",resultado.getString("name"));
```

este es mi método onPostExecute del AsyncTask :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject resultado=new JSONObject(s);
            if(resultado.getBoolean("estado")){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,                                                                                                 
                NavigationActivity.class);
                Bundle b= new Bundle();
                b.putString("name",resultado.getString("name"));
                b.putString("email",resultado.getString("email"));
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: En el LogCat que busca donde diga "Caused by" ,  ya que me parece esa línea de código no es la que produce el error.

Answer (score 0):

Esta soluccionado, mi problema era que lo que recibia del servicio web, era
el json tipo: 
estado:"true", mensaje:"Ejecutado con exito...", resultados={first_name="..", email="...", photo="..."}.
Y lo que buscaba eran los datos json de resultados. Entonces hice

> JSONObject user= resultado.getJSONObject("resultados");

Y para asignarle al bundle:

> b.putString("first_name",user.getString("first_name"));